# not able to submit form without page reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following code that i wish to use to submit form without reloading the page, but it reloads the entire page and when checked in console the script.php page is also not getting executed.

Code on index.php page

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var dataString = 'name=' + name;
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "script.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#result').html(response);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" name="form">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

code on script.php page

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Can anyone please tell how i can submit the form without reloading the page and also display the result from script.php page on index.php page

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` and `$(".submit").click(function(event) {` in form `submit` event.Its a well known question. Please do search before asking question.

Comment: @ Parth Trivedi page is still getting reloaded

Comment: Please remove `</button>` from your html. and use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

update your function. pass event object in function. and use event.preventDefault() to prevent default submit action.

```
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: page is still reloading

Comment: correct your html. there is closing button tag at the end. remove it and check
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**OR**

```
<input type="button"  class="submit" />Submit
```

Comment: page is still getting reloaded

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: <button type="button"  class="submit">SUBMIT</button> write like this @samuel and are you sure your page have only one submit class

Comment: yup i have only one class, the page is not reloading now but the script.php is also not running

Comment: i am not getting any error in console so not able to identify it

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix form `submit` and button `click`.

If you are a `click` event of `button` then use `type="button"` and if you are doing `$("form").submit()` then use `type="submit"`.

Also check for

```
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

and check your `ajax` post `data` , do

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",     
            //changes made here           
            data: { name: $("#name").val()},
            //changes made here. you have not written response
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: now the page is not getting reloaded but the script.php is not getting executed

Comment: what error you are getting in your browser console? you should use `baseURL+ "script.php"` as `ajax` `url`. Does your ajax works? Please check in your browser console.

Comment: tried it but the script is not running and i am not getting any error in console

Comment: @samuel did you get `console.log(dataString);` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100932/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-samuel).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data from the script.php page back to your index.php page. Swich out the little bit of ajax for this:

```
  $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "script.php",  
            data: "datastring",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(dataType){  
                $("#result").html(dataType); 
            }       
        });
```

In your script.php:

```
<?php
   $name=$_POST['name'];
   echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening to the input's `click` event, you should listen to the form's `submit`.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#name-form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form id="name-form" method="post" name="form">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: page is getting reloaded and script is not executing